# Resolving conflicts with language subfolder and langage param

Tags: .htaccess, joomla, url-rewriting

On a multilingual joomla website, i have virtual subfolders for each langage, like this :

- example.com/**en**/category/page
- example.com/**de**/category/page
- example.com/**fr**/category/page

But, in Google Webmaster Tools, i have 404 when it crawl on this :

- example.com/**en**/category/page?lang=**de**
- example.com/**de**/category/page?lang=**fr**
- etc.

I tried this :

```
RewriteRule ^en/mypage$ http://www.example.com/en/mypage? [L,R=301]
```

But of course it make looping redirection that doesn't work.

How can I solve this kind of problem?

Is there a way to replace the langage param to always get something like this :

- example.com/**en**/category/page?lang=**en**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then one solution would be to change your site map. This is how I usually do it on my multilingual Joomla sites.

1 - Install [Xmap](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/structure-a-navigation/site-map/3066)

2 - From the Joomla backend > Xmap, I create a new site map and under the menu option, I include all the menu links I want to be indexed, in all languages

3 - After publishing and saving, note the Xmap ID for this new site map.

4 - Create a new text file, similar to below. Save this to the root of your website as sitemap.xml
Note that you may need to change the xmap id to mantch 3 above, and you will need to add a `<loc>` entry for each language on your site

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
   <sitemap>
      <loc>http://your_domain/index.php?option=com_xmap&amp;view=xml&amp;id=1&amp;lang=en</loc>
   </sitemap>
   <sitemap>
      <loc>http://your_domain/index.php?option=com_xmap&amp;view=xml&amp;id=1&amp;lang=fr</loc>
   </sitemap>
</sitemapindex>
```

5 - Check that you can now reach the sitemaps for each language directly using the URLs from your `<loc>` lines above, e.g.:

```
http://your_domain/index.php?option=com_xmap&amp;view=xml&amp;id=1&amp;lang=en
```

6 - Submit `http://your_domain/sitemap.xml` to Webmaster tools as the location of your site map. Google is smart enough to fgure out the language settings after that.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It's a little late but here the solution i used (David's answer was a very good start).

Xmap didn't exist anymore, and OSmap isn't the best solution because it doesn't follow the Google recommandations for multilingual sitemaps, wich says that it needs `<xhtml:link rel="alternate"[...]` for each links.

So : I used OSmap to get all links quiclky; then I manually create a properly formatted sitemap. Then I posted my sitemaps to webmaster tools (I got one for each language), and i place a sitemap_index.xml to help crawlers to find them.